# How to get water inside a space suit?

Tags: spacesuits, water

How is water transferred from outside the suit to inside the suit?

Comment: If an astronaut wearing a space suit gets dehydrated during an EVA, something was wrong about EVA planing and implementation.

Comment: @Uwe the Apollo port wasn't for EVA, see my answer.

Comment: If an astronaut on an EVA gets dehydrated, it means one or more of three things have happened: (1) the suit has malfunctioned, (2) something is wrong with the astronaut, or (3) the EVA has gone on far longer than planned. In all cases, the response is for the astronaut to return to the vehicle and get out of the spacesuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apollo suits had a "food/drink port" but it was [apparently never used](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/alsj-DrinkFood.html).  The [main purpose of the port](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/AERTND7720Food.pdf) was to allow the crew to eat and drink in a contingency situation where the vehicle was depressurized and they had to survive in the suits for an extended period of time.

> In  case of  complete  loss of cabin  pressure during  a  mission, 
>   the crewmen  might  be  required  to wear  pressurized  suits  continuously for as  long as  115  hours.  Water  would  be available  by
>   passing the  probe  of  the potable-water  dispenser  through  the
>   hel­met feedport.

[image]

Current US suits have an [internal drink bag](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qlo_kJwtyZoC&pg=PA327&lpg=PA327&dq=emu%20drink%20bag&source=bl&ots=BKzyC-QtEz&sig=ACfU3U1TWzlfOIwzv8SiZXlG1lWEJD-BJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwilgeKozI7gAhVLs6wKHcB_AeEQ6AEwEHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=emu%20drink%20bag&f=false).

[image]
(image [here](https://picryl.com/media/s113e05281-sts-113-disposable-in-suit-drink-bag-for-an-sts-113-emu-387614))

Comment: reading the linked PDF on Internet Archive and this is right up front: "The JSC Director waived the use of the International System of Units (SI) for this Technical Note, because, in his judgment, the use of SI units would impair the usefulness of the report or result in excessive cost." Even as far back as 1974, who cares about the SI mandate

Comment: There must have been some requirement to waive though at the time, which is something, I guess.